# Change GraphicsDeviceManager device in SharpDX

Tags: sharpdx

I am using sharpdx with winRT to develope DirectX app.
I just started and confused with GraphicsDeviceManager. Does it allow to change or set adapter on which it created? (if I have few adapters for ex.)
I didn`t find how to set it or change.

I can create new with GraphicsDevice.New(...), but it returns new device, which cannot be applyed to existing GraphicsDeviceManager.

Any ideas? Maybe someone already faced with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Solved. You need to subscribe to the PreparingDeviceSettings event where you can override various settings including adapter via its event arguments